# thread 1: signal SIGABRT error app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

whenever i try and run my app it crashes and goes to this goes to my main.m file and

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

is highlighted in green and tells me "thread 1:signal SIGABRT and when i put an exception breakpoint it says "thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 How can i fix this problem so my app doesn't crash anymore?

and it gives me this at the bottom

argv    char ** 0xbfffee18  0xbfffee18

argc    int 1   1

when i add an exception breakpoint this is highlighted in green

0x15dd8b9:  pushl  %ebp

so is this

0x29df9b:  xorl   %eax, %eax

and this

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

how can i fix this so my app runs correctly? please help!

Comment: Add Exception Breakpoint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/300798

Comment: It is impossible to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: i am new to this so what part of the code do you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

first of all it says why it crashes.
also check if

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

is called. if is called - then it crashes in another place. for some reason it doesn't show actually where it crashed

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

Comment: that is what mine looks like so what am i supposed to do. i am new to to making apps.

Comment: how can i fix the problem so my app runs?

Comment: add a breakpoint there or right after this line add

    NSLog(@"IT PASS IN FUNCTION");

and you must be able to see it in log above stacktrace.

Answer (score -1):

actually , its so easy if it shows an SIGBART error , it means any button is not given action correctlly or more than one action is given to a button, so the solutionis  go to outlets inspecter and check the segues connected  to the buttons , if you find more actions to single button , delete all of the actions and create a new fresh action to the button , that's it problem solved